# Preview doesn't match actual answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-preview

Today I stumbled upon [an answer that wasn't properly formatted](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/419/what-can-i-say-politely-when-something-bad-happens/438#438). But when I tried to edit it I noticed the preview was showing the answer with proper formatting. I feel the OP is not using the formatting correctly, yet I feel the shown answer should match the preview.

The answer:
[image: The shown answer:]

The preview:
[image: The preview:]

Comment: Looks like some old bug that got fixed in the passing years, hence the correct preview - any trivial edit will also "fix" the link format.

Comment: Apparently it's NOREPRO here on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274574/302251.

Comment: Both of your comments are so interesting! And I guess both are correct.